Как разбить записи на группы по сумме?
Есть таблица, отсортированная по полю kolich в обратном порядке:



id
kolich




7863
5392


3230
2321


3821
1914


10595
1524


11397
1395


10602
952


10612
829


10611
828


10081
670



Как получить такую таблицу:



id
kolich
grupa




7863
5392
1


3230
2321
2


3821
1914
3


10595
1524
4


11397
1395
5


10602
952
6


10612
829
6


10611
828
7


10081
670
7



чтобы уникальная grupa присваивалась идущим подряд записям,сумма(kolich) которых меньше 2000?
То есть подряд идущие записи должны в сумме давать <2000, а если следующая запись превышает этот лимит, то ей присваивается новая группа на примере выше это группы (grupa) 6 и 7
Полагаю это можно реализовать оконной функцией с промежуточными итогами. Пока хожу возле:
SUM(count(*)) OVER (
    PARTITION BY case when count(*) < 2000 then id else count(*) end
    ORDER BY kolich rows between unbounded preceding and current row
)
AS rns


Вы правильно полагаете. Что вам мешает это осуществить?

подряд идущие записи - это предполагает сортировку по какому-то полю. По какому?

@AlexanderPetrov по полю kolich

@rotabor нехватка нейронов. Пока хожу возле:
sum(count(*)) OVER(PARTITION BY case when count(*) < 2000 then id else count(*) end ORDER BY kolich rows between unbounded preceding and current row) AS rns

А какая целевая СУБД?

@rotabor, ой забыл указать: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0

Значение номера группы зависит от предыдущих записей. Всех. А коли так, то только рекурсивный CTE.

Зачем такие сложные вопросы задавать? Возможно, лучшим выходом будет использование внешнего обработчика. Условие группировки довольно сложное. По сути, нужно искать первую сумму, которая больше или равна 2000, а потом отбрасывать последнюю запись, если она не единственная.

Такая задача довольно часто встречается - набрать группы строк не больше определенного размера. Например, для заполнения грузов в контейнер или грузовик.
Как уже комментировал @Akina, нужен рекурсивный запрос.
Перебираем строки по одной в цикле (рекурсии).
Запрос достаточно простой, можете адаптировать под Oracle.
Посмотрите вариант решения (для Postgresql)
with recursive 
 t as(select *,row_number()over(order by kolich desc) rn from test)
,r as(
  select *
    ,kolich ts
    ,1 grn
  from t
  where rn=1
  union all
  select t.*
    ,case when (r.ts+t.kolich)>2000 then t.kolich
     else r.ts+t.kolich
     end ts
    ,case when (r.ts+t.kolich)>2000 then r.grn+1
     else r.grn
     end grn
  from r inner join t on (t.rn=r.rn+1)
)
select * from r order by rn;

Результат



id
kolich
rn
ts
grn




7863
5392
1
5392
1


3230
2321
2
2321
2


3821
1914
3
1914
3


10595
1524
4
1524
4


11397
1395
5
1395
5


10602
952
6
952
6


10612
829
7
1781
6


10611
828
8
828
7


10081
670
9
1498
7



Demo

Это работает! Вы гений!!

Наберёте 50 баллов, не забудьте про upvote для этого ответа.

Предлагаю решение на c#:
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
class IdKolich {
    public int id, kolich, grupa;
    public IdKolich(int id, int kolich)
        { this.id = id; this.kolich = kolich; grupa = 0; }
    public override string ToString()
        { return string.Format("{0,10}{1,10}{2,10}", id, kolich, grupa); }
}
static class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        // тестовые данные
        var iks = new IdKolich[] { new IdKolich(7863, 5392),
            new IdKolich(3230, 2321),
            new IdKolich(3821, 1914),
            new IdKolich(10595, 1524),
            new IdKolich(11397, 1395),
            new IdKolich(10602, 952),
            new IdKolich(10612, 829),
            new IdKolich(10611, 828),
            new IdKolich(10081, 670) };
        // решение
        int i = iks[0].kolich >= 2000 ? 0 : 1;
        iks.Aggregate(0, (stot, cur) => {
                if ((stot += cur.kolich) >= 2000) { i++; stot = cur.kolich; }
                cur.grupa = i; return stot;
            } );
        // вавод результата
        foreach (var ik in iks) Console.WriteLine(ik);
    }
}

-->
      7863      5392         1
      3230      2321         2
      3821      1914         3
     10595      1524         4
     11397      1395         5
     10602       952         6
     10612       829         6
     10611       828         7
     10081       670         7

